# how to invoke a shell script in remote node through ansible and input a series of run time values to that shell script from local node

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

1. I have a script called configAdmin.sh in remote node. I need to
   invoke that script from local node, later it will open below session
   and prompts for input.

   some input like connect to domain
       ConfigAdmin> -->

   How can I achieve this through ansible?

Answer (score 0):

To run a remote script that expects commands from standard input, you can use `shell` and provide the commands before your script with a pipe:

```
- shell: echo "some command" | myscript
```

Comment: Hi Argov, I have a shell script in my remote note called configadmin.sh. When I execute it, It will invoke ConfigAdmin> session and we can enter commands or pass inputs. Same thing How I can achieve through ansible? When I run the configAdmin.sh from ansible node... How can I pass the inputs to that particular script?

Comment: Do you want ansible to prompt the user for the answers, or have the answers ready in advance and just provide them for the script?

Comment: I want ansible to prompt the user for the answers Argov. Can you please guide me.

Comment: Gladly, just let me understand exactly what you need - do you want ansible to act as some kind of proxy - to forward the user answers to the script on a remote machine?

Comment: yes argov. That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I need to pass the run time values to the script in the remote machine.

Comment: Do you know in advance what the questions will be? Or do you want it to be a full interactive proxy?

Comment: actually there are no questions argov. That script is one tool through which I can execute series of commands. Pasting the instructions below. Run the script configAdmin.bat --> use this command to import file like that.

Comment: Argov, How can we make it as a full interactive proxy?

Comment: I don't think you can make it a full proxy - not easily at least. If the commands are known in advance, you can use `shell` to run the script and provide the commands to standard input with a simple pipe

Comment: that can solve my problem argov. Can you help me how to achieve that.

Comment: Argov, I mean how to execute what you have said through ansible?

Comment: I will try using that simple pipe argov.

Comment: Argov, Can you tell me how to install pexpect in my machine?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you mis-typed `expect`, then that's just an ansible module.